# A way to access common FTP connection resource pool in Ruby across AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax, resources, ftp, connection

I have a web application which establishes many FTP or SFTP connections with outside servers. Its interface uses AJAX, and via AJAX I get file listings on remote FTP servers and return those to the client browser.

Each time I run an AJAX call, I have to reconnect to the remote server and reauthenticate. This takes a ton of extra time.

Is there a way I can somehow store FTP connection resource objects in some common memory pool and re-access to the connection resource objects with future AJAX calls? I tried Memcached, but it looks like it's not possible to store connection resources there. Maybe I could store them in a thread and somehow access them there? Any other ideas?

I could always have a daemon manage connections and act as a proxy, but that feels overkill.

Comment: Did I answer your question...?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this method will work, as I don't think it will allow me to keep a pool of FTP connections alive and re-access them across httpd processes. I might be wrong though...I have not gotten to a point where I can write a prototype. If I end up using the method you described, I will definitely come back here and mark your suggestion as the answer. I may just end up using a daemon though.

Comment: The point is that you don't need a 'pool', just one connection per worker. A worker only processes one request at a time and thus only 1 connection is required. If you did need 2 connections per worker you could simply make 2 connections instead of 1 in the `on_event` handler. Workers stay around for a while, so the connection will get re-used as long as the worker stays around, and a new worker will also result in a new connection.

Comment: What's with the down-vote people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making this work using global variables (eg. $my_global). I have a ConnectionPooler singleton class which manages connections stored in a hash. Easy as pie.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Feedback / an explanation would be good for both  me and the community. Just because someone doesn't like a solution doesn't mean it is not a workable, decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a connection for each worker/app process you have. For example, with passenger:

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
      # connect to ftp server
    end
  end
end
```

With Rails this would go into `environment.rb`.

That said, I'm not sure if this is a great idea though since I don't use ftp much.

Comment: Seems like this would spawn a new thread for each AJAX call, opening a new connection in each, correct? I would like ONE place (thread, commonly-accessible memory pool, whatever) which stores a hash of the connections, and I want to regain access to connections stored in the hash during AJAX calls.

Comment: No, this connects when passenger starts a worker. Workers are re-used between requests (well, for a while anyway, there's a bunch of details here you can affect via configuration, and others you can read about in their docs).