# A way to share a variable across multiple httpd threads with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, shared-memory

Let's say I have the following threading in my Rails web application:

```
class MyController
  def my_action
    count = 0
    arr = []

    10.times do |i|
      arr[i] = Thread.new {
        sleep(rand(0)/10.0)
        Thread.current["mycount"] = count
        count += 1
      }
    end

    arr.each {|t| t.join; print t["mycount"], ", " }
    puts "count = #{count}"
  end
end
```

As you can see, the 'count' variable is shared across all threads.

**Now,** what I want to do is **share 'count'** across multiple httpd requests and **allow my_action in MyController to have access to that variable**. For instance, maybe whatever spawns the ruby process to serve httpd process could hold the variable count in its scope, and then the ruby processes spawned for httpd processes could then access that variable.

Using memcached, a database, and session variables is out of the question. Ultimately 'count' will actually be a resource object...an FTP connection.

Is this possible? Perhaps using Apache/Passenger workers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471680/a-way-to-access-common-ftp-connection-resource-pool-in-ruby-across-ajax-calls/4471758#4471758)?

Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Rails is single-threaded by design, so I don't believe what you are trying to do is possible or advisable.  At least, I've never seen it done before.

Comment: Well that sucks. There has to be some way to pull something like this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly this is possible using global variables. Global variables in Rails are those that start with a dollar sign, like $count.

Comment: won't globals involve race conditions unless access is synchronized?

Comment: Depending on your use, I suppose so. I was just using one to keep an FTP connection active across HTTP requests -- and it worked beautifully.